# Can't remotely connect to MongoDB through an SSH channel

Tags: mongodb, ssh, remote-access, robo3t

I am having an issue connecting to a mongoDB through SSH. I commented out the bind_ip option (and then added the authorization option). But to no avail. I even allowed the port through my firewalls. I get this error

"Cannot establish SSH Tunnel (IP:22).
Error: Failed to create a SSH channel"

It is worth mentioning I am using Robo 3T, and the first step, connecting to the server passes.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

Select whether Compass should connect to a MongoDB cluster via an SSH tunnel, which automatically starts when you connect to MongoDB, and stops when you disconnect. If selected, choose either a password or an identity file to provide authentication.

Link: https://docs.mongodb.com/compass/master/connect/